# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: 11.10, apt, apache2, mysql, php

I'm trying to connect my PHP page to MySQL database, but I'm getting this error :
**`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`**
 I'm working on Ubuntu 11.10 MySQL 5.5 and PHP 5.3.
I have also installed the apache2 server, and it works fine.
I tried to install the php5-mysql module using the following command:
**`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`**
I get this error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1) but 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install **`php5-common`** again but nothing was successful.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). The answer here may help.  Especially the section about sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

**`php5-mysql : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1)`**. This means that php5-mysql was looking for php5-common (=5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1) but I had php5-common (=5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9) installed. I removed the package php5-common (=5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9) which is when the default php5-common (=5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1) was there. I reinstalled the other packages which got removed when I removed php5-common with the following command
**`sudo apt-get install php5-cli`**
**`sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`**
**`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`**
and restarted apache2. Now it works fine.